# Torque on a line

Tags: torque

I need to calculate the torque of a line in 2D of length $L_0$.

We choose $0\leq x\leq L_0$, and then the pivot point is in $x=L_p$.

We have a force vectorial $F$ acting on the line.

For me, the torque is

$$(-\sin\theta,\cos\theta)\cdot\int_0^{L_0}F(x)|x-L_p|dx$$

but in the book appears

$$(-\sin\theta,\cos\theta)\cdot\int_0^{L_0}F(x)(x-L_p)dx$$

Why is this difference?

$\theta$ is the slope of the line.

[image]

Comment: Is this a mathematical line, a rope of some sort, or something else?  If it is something like a rope, note that torque cannot be applied to a rope.

Comment: it is a line with a constant mass density $m_0$